# Upload Bandwidth usage when you become seed of a torrent

Tags: bittorrent, bandwidth

When I become the seed for a torrent and leecher tries to download from my computer, the data from my computer must be uploaded so that it is available to others. Doesn't it affect my upload bandwidth usage?

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusions are correct so far. When uploading to a leecher, your upload bandwidth will be taken up by however much you allow the leecher to download from you. Most bittorrent applications offer a way to throttle upload speeds though in case you have limited upload bandwidth and need to keep other things running smoothly.

Comment: is the bandwidth of upload and download different?